# Help with Joining two Tables

Tags: mysql, database

I know this has been asked a dozen times here at stackoverflow, but it is driving me mad.

I have two tables:

1. card_lookup_values (which contains: `card_id, card_price`)
2. card_sales (which contains: `discount_price`)

They both contain `card_id` (so I know I can join them there), but how exactly would I join them? What I am trying to accomplish is to multiply the card's price it's discount price to get the actual sale price, but it is proving to be a real head scratcher.

Comment: You really want to multiply those values to get the actual sale price?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  card_lookup_values.card_id,
  card_lookup_values.card_price,
 card_sales.discount_price,
  card_sales.discount_price * card_lookup_values.card_price AS actual_price
FROM card_lookip_values JOIN card_sales ON card_lookup_values.card_id = card_sales.card_id
```

Or, if your discounts are something like "20% off", the following subtracts the amount discounted (discount * original) from the original to return the new price.

```
card_lookup_values.card_price - (card_sales.discount_price * card_lookup_values.card_price) AS actual_price
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. I really do appreciate the help (and to everyone else who gave their input). I did just try to run the query, and I am receiving an error on line 5 (the line which has the actual math.

Comment: @Louis Comma was missing on the line above it `card_sales.discount_price,`

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from card_lookup_values clv
left join card_sales cs on clv.card_id = cs.card_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select card_price*discount_price from card_lookup_values inner join card_sales
on card_lookup_values.card_id = card_sales.card_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select clv.card_price,cs.discount_price card_lookup_values clv inner join card_sales cs on cs.card_id=clv.card_id
```

Edit the select part to do your respective calculation by using the right alias for ur table cos multiplying the discount price Nd the card price to get sm number didn't make any sense to me as it doesn't reprsetpnt anything